# trying to create trigger, create never executes

Tags: mysql, trigger

I am trying to define a trigger in MySQL and the language to create it never executes. I have already defined and inserted data into the database with no problem.

This is the start of my trigger. As you can see I put some giberish in there to illustrate that this never executes because it produces no errors at all.

```
delimiter //

snthd\-
\qeiksdhsnthd-/rcg dsth
o;eui;r/cf/r
\qk-xnthr/cf


CREATE TRIGGER deleted_insert
ON item
AFTER UPDATE,INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
        ...etc body of trigger

END;

delimiter ;
```

Executing this does absolutely nothing and does not return any output from the sql server. If I do not change the delimiter, then it does execute but produces a syntax error on the 'ON' keyword.

How can simply declare this trigger?

Comment: It looks like you're using T-SQL / Microsoft SQL Server syntax, not MySQL syntax.

Comment: Doesn’t look like you’re terminating with the // delimiter you declare at the beginning.

Comment: The syntax for [CREATE TRIGGER in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-trigger.html).